# Weblogic Stuck Thread on JDBC call

Tags: jdbc, weblogic, connection-pooling

We frequently get a series of Stuck threads on our Weblogic servers. I've analyzed this over a period of time.

What I'd like to understand is whether this stuck thread block indicates *it is still reading data from the open socket to the database* since the queries are simple SELECT stuff?

```
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
        at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:239)
        at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:92)
```

We've run netstat and other commands, the sockets from the Weblogic app server to the Database match the number of connections in the pool.

Any ideas what else we should be investigating here?

**Stack trace of thread dump:**

```
"[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon prio=10 tid=0x61a5b000 nid=0x25f runnable [0x6147b000..0x6147eeb0]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
        at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:239)
        at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:92)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:172)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:117)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:92)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:77)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1023)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:999)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:584)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:183)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.fetch(T4CStatement.java:1000)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.close_or_fetch_from_next(OracleResultSetImpl.java:314)
        - locked <0x774546e0> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.next(OracleResultSetImpl.java:228)
        - locked <0x774546e0> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection)
        at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.ResultSet_oracle_jdbc_driver_OracleResultSetImpl.next(Unknown Source)
```

The bit starting from `weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run` to here has been omitted. We have 8 sets of thread dumps - and each show the thread waiting on the same line, and the same object locked

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.close_or_fetch_from_next(OracleResultSetImpl.java:314)
        - locked <0x774546e0> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection)
```

Comment: Is `weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.ResultSet_oracle_jdbc_driver_OracleResultSetImpl.next` the bottom of the stack?

Comment: @antispam: nope, the rest is our code calling this via springframework API.

Comment: `StuckThreadMaxTime` is counting from `weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute`. Maybe database is not the only place to look for...

Comment: @antispam: true, but we have 8 sets of TDs taken across 4 minutes, and the thread is on the same line `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.close_or_fetch_from_next(OracleResultSetImpl.java:314) - locked <0x773c1758> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection)`

Comment: @JoseK could you please let me know what was the issue in your case ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the time the stack was printed, it seems blocked waiting for more data from the server

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.next(OracleResultSetImpl.java:228)
```

Maybe it is just the query which is taking more than `StuckThreadMaxTime`and WL issues a Warning.

If possible I would try:

- Find which query or queries are getting the threads stuck and check execution time
- Use Wireshark to analyze communication with database
- Have a look at the driver source code (JD comes to mind) to understand stack trace

Comment: The queries vary across the stack traces - it's not always the same one, and we've run statspack on the Oracle database across different days - but have not found a long running query.

The wireshark & driver are a good thing to do next. Will check for the latest driver versions first

Comment: We've found our driver is in `ojdbc6.jar` and we use JDK1.6 connecting to Oracle 10.2.0.4 db. Some debate on whether we should try with `ojdbc14.jar` instead since the db is not Oracle 11

Comment: AFAIK, it's recommended to use latest JDBC as it's backward compatible with 10g and has some bugfixes (see http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Connecting+JIRA+to+Oracle#ConnectingJIRAtoOracle-3.CopytheOracledrivertoyourapplicationserver)

Answer (score 6):

if you use weblogic debug flag -Dweblogic.debug.DebugJDBCSQL you will be able to trace the SQL which is actually being executed